# return String from a callback - Java

Tags: java, string, callback, return

does anyone know how I can solve the following problem. I want to return a String from a callback, but I get only "The final local variable s cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type", because of final.

```
 public String getConstraint(int indexFdg) {
    final String s;
    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace();
        }

        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            s = result;
        }
    };
    SpeicherService.Util.getInstance().getConstraint(indexFdg, callback);
    return s;
    }
```

Comment: `AsyncCallback` cannot return a value.  But `Callable<T>` can.  Usually what I would do is make this a `Callable`, pass it to an executor service, and use the returned `Future<T>` to get the returned value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The whole point of an asynchronous callback is to notify you of something that happens asynchronously, at some time in the future.  You can't return `s` from `getConstraint` if it's going to be set *after* the method has finished running.

When dealing with asynchronous callbacks you have to rethink the flow of your program.  Instead of `getConstraint` returning a value, the code that would go on to **use** that value should be called as a result of the callback.

As a simple (incomplete) example, you would need to change this:

```
 String s = getConstraint();
 someGuiLabel.setText(s);
```

Into something like this:

```
 myCallback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
     public void onSuccess(String result) {
         someGuiLabel.setText(result);
     }
 }
 fetchConstraintAsynchronously(myCallback);
```

### Edit

A popular alternative is the concept of a *future*.  A future is an object that you can return immediately but which will only have a value at some point in the future.  It's a container where you only need to wait for the value at the point of asking for it.

You can think of holding a future as holding a ticket for your suit that is at the dry cleaning.  You get the ticket immediately, can keep it in your wallet, give it to a friend... but as soon as you need to exchange it for the actual suit you need to wait until the suit is ready.

Java has such a class ([`Future<V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)) that is used widely by the [ExecutorService API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, from the result of the callback I have to update the UI. I have adopted the same technique that you mentioned, but the problem in my case it has become cyclic like A - > B and again B -> A, where A is the UI class and B is the class that has the callBack. Is it a good practice to keep it that way or can you suggest any other alternatives? Like UI class calls the callback and callback calls the UI again.

Comment: @AtulKumar: We'd probably need some more details to know whether it's a problem.  If it's causing a concrete problem, it might be appropriate to ask a question with a minimal example that reproduces the question.  If you're asking generally about the design, it might be appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.   In general I'd say mutual dependencies aren't in themselves a deal breaker, and are common in patterns like MVC (where the view and controller know about each other).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative workaround is to define a new class, called `SyncResult`

```
public class SyncResult {
    private static final long TIMEOUT = 20000L;
    private String result;

    public String getResult() {
        long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (result == null && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis < TIMEOUT) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(TIMEOUT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your code to this

```
public String getConstraint(int indexFdg) {
    final SyncResult syncResult = new SyncResult();
    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace();
        }

        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            syncResult.setResult(result);
        }
    };
    SpeicherService.Util.getInstance().getConstraint(indexFdg, callback);
    return syncResult.getResult();
}
```

The `getResult()` method will be blocked until `setResult(String)` method been called or the `TIMEOUT` reached.